# ESB MULE Testing - Utility tools

Tags: testing, mule

Are there any utility tools for ESB MULE , just similar to RFHUTIL for IBM MQ . We are testing for integration through MULE using Webservices , Queues and also REST . any utility tools would help

Comment: What exactly do you want the tools to do?  You can use various routers (like `wire-tap`) to send messages to multiple locations.  And/or you can use dependency injection to send to a test location.  See [the Mule routers page](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Routing+Message+Processors) for more routers.  There is also logging and remote debugging.

Comment: RFHUTIL for WMB/WMQ is a queue testing tool. RFHUTIL is perfectly fine for Mule ESB given you use it with WMQ. Mule ESB does not feature a queue system (I'm not counting VM queues), you need to supply some external, ActiveMQ, RabbitMQ, HornetQ or WebSphere MQ are popular choices. The question does not make much sense as it is now.

Comment: Thanks @eebbesen am looking for any GUI tools , which will help me in testing XML's flowing from one system to another ... Mule will be the integrating the two systems ....